# Jaydata knockout memory leak

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jaydata

I've a problem with memory leak on a SPA written with jaydata, and knockout plugin.

In my app, the sequence is:

1. var x = (load a jaydata object)
2. var obs = x.asKoObservable()
3. ( use obs on a given viewModel to use it in a UI )
4. dispose everything related to ko.computed()'s and manual ko subscriptions (with subs.dispose())
5. Force GC on Chrome
6. Take a "Heap Snapshot" on Chrome

Here is see the original 'obs' being alive after GC... and it seems the culprit is a 'koProperty' referencing 'obs'...

The given koProperty is defined on knockout.js:48 of the ko plugin for jaydata.

Also on line 50 later, that koProperty has a manual subscription... that i not stored nor disposed on the plugin context

Anybody can confirm this? If so... there is a bug? which causes my memory leaks?

Comment: have you turned on advanced heap snapshot properties in the dev tools settings?  We are finding that Chrome is keeping stuff alive due to V8 optimizations but you'll only find that out if you can see the advanced snapshot.

Comment: I've found that koProperty is missing the var keyword, which makes that a global variable, which then holds a refetence to the last observable defined here